# how to replace data by comparing the occurence of different groups in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame "DF" in which the first four columns are the count data for the four unique character strings in column S1 to S10

```
        DF = read.table(text="AA    BB  AB  NC  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  S10
    R1  0   5   5   0   BB  AB  AB  BB  AB  AB  BB  BB  BB  AB
    R2  5   0   4   1   AB  AA  AB  AB  AA  AA  AB  NC  AA  AA
    R3  1   7   2   0   AA  AB  BB  BB  BB  BB  BB  BB  AB  BB
    R4  4   0   1   5   AA  AA  AB  NC  NC  AA  NC  AA  NC  NC
    R5  0   5   3   2   AB  BB  AB  AB  BB  BB  NC  BB  NC  BB
    R6  4   4   1   1   AB  BB  AA  AA  BB  AA  AA  BB  BB  NC", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

at first I would test the ratio of the numbers of column "AA" and column "BB" to find out which rows' data need to be replaced.

```
         pvalue <- apply(DF[,c("AA","BB")], 1, function(x) {
          chisq.test(as.vector(x), p = c(0.5,0.5))$p.value
     })
     pvalue
```

So some data in R1 to R5 need to be replaced if pvalue <=0.05. 
The character strings with the largest number between Column "AB" and "NC" will be changed to the character strings with the lowest number between "AA" and "BB"
For example, in R1 row, the largest number is column "AB" between columns "AB" and "NC", the lowest number is column "AA" between Columns "AA" and "BB. So the character "AB" in column S1 to S10 will be changed to 
"AA". 
for R2, change "AB" to "BB", 
for R3, change "AB" to "AA"
for R4, change "NC" to "BB"
....

So the expected result is:

```
           S1   S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  S10
    R1  BB  AA  AA  BB  AA  AA  BB  BB  BB  AA
    R2  BB  AA  BB  BB  AA  AA  BB  NC  AA  AA
    R3  AA  AA  BB  BB  BB  BB  BB  BB  AA  BB
    R4  AA  AA  AB  BB  BB  AA  BB  AA  BB  BB
    R5  AA  BB  AA  AA  BB  BB  NC  BB  NC  BB
    R6  AB  BB  AA  AA  BB  AA  AA  BB  BB  NC
```

It is a little complicated. Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `apply` function find the new and old value extracting the names of columns that comply the condicion max and min

```
DF2 <- t(apply(DF[pvalue <= 0.05, ], 1, function(x){
  x <- gsub(names(x[which.max(as.integer(x[3:4]))+2]), 
            names(x[which.min(as.integer(x[1:2]))]), x)
}))


DF2

   AA  BB  AB  NC  S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6   S7   S8   S9   S10 
R1 "0" "5" "5" "0" "BB" "AA" "AA" "BB" "AA" "AA" "BB" "BB" "BB" "AA"
R2 "5" "0" "4" "1" "BB" "AA" "BB" "BB" "AA" "AA" "BB" "NC" "AA" "AA"
R3 "1" "7" "2" "0" "AA" "AA" "BB" "BB" "BB" "BB" "BB" "BB" "AA" "BB"
R4 "4" "0" "1" "5" "AA" "AA" "AB" "BB" "BB" "AA" "BB" "AA" "BB" "BB"
R5 "0" "5" "3" "2" "AA" "BB" "AA" "AA" "BB" "BB" "NC" "BB" "NC" "BB"
```

or if you replace the rows in your current `DF` object:

```
DF[pvalue <= 0.05, ] <- t(apply(DF[pvalue <= 0.05, ], 1, function(x){
   x <- gsub(names(x[which.max(as.integer(x[3:4]))+2]), 
             names(x[which.min(as.integer(x[1:2]))]), x)
 }))

 DF
   AA BB AB NC S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 S10
R1  0  5  5  0 BB AA AA BB AA AA BB BB BB  AA
R2  5  0  4  1 BB AA BB BB AA AA BB NC AA  AA
R3  1  7  2  0 AA AA BB BB BB BB BB BB AA  BB
R4  4  0  1  5 AA AA AB BB BB AA BB AA BB  BB
R5  0  5  3  2 AA BB AA AA BB BB NC BB NC  BB
R6  4  4  1  1 AB BB AA AA BB AA AA BB BB  NC
```

Comment: In your last solution, if the count numbers (the first four columns in DF) also need to be updated, how to do that within your code?

Comment: How should AA, BB, AB and NC be? Into the `apply` function after  `gsub` instruction `x[1:4] <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')` replaces first 4 cols ...